# Reading a csv file into D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to read in a file using D3 and I am using the following command

The file is like this:

```
HeaderA,HeaderB,HeaderC,...
EntryA1,EntryB1,EntryC1,...
EntryA2,EntryB2,EntryC2,...
...
EntryA128,EntryB128,EntryC128,...
```

The command I am using is

```
var globaldata

d3.csv("dataset.csv", function(error,data){
if (error){
console.log
}
else{
globaldata = data;
}
```

The problem I have is that when I run it and it reads in the data  I can enter `globaldata[0]` in the console and what I get is `HeaderA,EntryA1,HeaderB,EntryB1,...` however what I would like is to be able to maintain the structure so I can enter `globaldata[1][1]` and I get `EntryB1` for that etc.

Can someone explain where I am going wrong please.

Comment: So what happens when you enter `globaldata[1][1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `d3.csv.parseRows` instead of `d3.csv`. This will return an array of arrays representing the parsed rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parseRows` [method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parseRows) if you want all the file parsed. However, if you just want to have access to some rows, you can use the `parse` [method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) directly on that string, e.g.:

```
globalDataRow = d3.csv.parse(globaldata[1])
```

Then `globalDataRow[1]` would give you `EntryB1`.